# Add a gap in heatmap with pheatmap package

Tags: r, heatmap, pheatmap

I made the heatmap using the code below:

```
library(pheatmap)
library(dplyr)

data = data.frame(matrix(runif(10*10), ncol=10))
data$sample = rep(c("tumour", "normal"), 5)
data$subject.ID = paste('Subject', 1:10)
data = data %>% arrange(sample)

# for row annotation
my_sample_col = data %>% select(sample)
rownames(my_sample_col) = data$subject.ID
# data matrix
mat = as.matrix(data %>% select(-sample, -subject.ID))
rownames(mat) = data$subject.ID

pheatmap(mat,
         scale='row',
         annotation_row = my_sample_col,
         annotation_names_row=F,
         cluster_rows = FALSE,
         cluster_cols = FALSE,
         show_colnames = FALSE,
         show_rownames = FALSE)
```

I want to put a gap between row 5 and row 6, to separate the heatmap according to my row annotation.

In `pheatmap` function, the argument `gaps_row` seems to do the job.

```
vector of row indices that show shere to put gaps into heatmap. Used only if the rows are not clustered.
```

I'm not sure how to implement that. Can someone help me with this? Thanks a  lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend using `ComplexHeatmap` package ([website](https://jokergoo.github.io/ComplexHeatmap-reference/book/index.html); [Gu et al, 2016](https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/article/32/18/2847/1743594)). You can install it with `devtools::install_github("jokergoo/ComplexHeatmap")`.

It has more functionalities, but you also have to invest more time (eg., row annotation and matrix scaling).

```
library(ComplexHeatmap)

# Create annotation for rows
my_sample_col_ano <- rowAnnotation(sample = my_sample_col$sample,
                                   show_annotation_name = FALSE)

# Scale original matrix row-wise
matS <- t(apply(mat, 1, scale))

# Plot heatmap
Heatmap(matS, 
        # Remove name from fill legend
        name = "",
        # Keep original row/col order
        row_order = rownames(matS), column_order = colnames(matS),
        # Add left annotation (legend with tumor/normal) 
        left_annotation = my_sample_col_ano,
        # ACTUAL SPLIT by sample group 
        row_split = my_sample_col$sample,
        show_row_names = FALSE, show_column_names = FALSE,
        show_row_dend = FALSE, show_column_dend = FALSE,
        row_title = NULL)
```

[image]

If you want to use original `pheatmap` pass argument to `gaps_row` which is equal to the size of your group (ie, normal):

```
pheatmap(mat,
         scale='row',
         gaps_row = 5,
         annotation_row = my_sample_col,
         annotation_names_row=F,
         cluster_rows = FALSE,
         cluster_cols = FALSE,
         show_colnames = FALSE,
         show_rownames = FALSE)
```

If you can more groups than two instead of hardcoding numeric value to `gaps_row` (ie, `gaps_row = 5`) you can pass this snippet (`head(as.numeric(cumsum(table(my_sample_col$sample))), -1)`).

[image]